# Create ZNodes without cmd in Zookeeper

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, spring-cloud-zookeeper

I am trying to implement Configuration Management through Zookeeper. I have created few ZNodes from command line as:

1. create /config ""
2. create /config/mypocapp ""
3. create /config/mypocapp/name "John Doe"

Here, `name` is one of the properties that I want to access in my app called `mypocapp`.

Since we will be having a lot of properties in our application, we just can't use command line to create each and every property like this.

Is there a way we can create the properties in zookeeper through some UI or directly in a file (and import it to zookeeper).

I am completely new to zookeeper and not getting any help in this direction. Please help.

Comment: how about use java sdk like curator and write code to create ?

Comment: This is the only option I see for now. I also came across Exhibitor and it seems to work well, but it doesn't support bulk import as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exhibitor is one of the options that one can try to insert, modify or delete properties in ZNodes.

One can follow the steps given below:

1. Download the pom file of Exhibitor UI from the Github.
2. Built the pom file using maven that will generate a jar file.
3. Run the jar file as: `java -jar <jar-file-name>.jar -c file`
4. Go to your browser and type in: localhost:8080 to access Exhibitor UI.
5. Here, you can configure your Zookeeper ensemble and can edit the properties.
6. Please note that each instance of Zookeeper will have corresponding Exhibitor UI.
7. In order to run exhibitor on a different port, you can run:

   `java -jar <jar-file-name>.jar -c file --port <port-of-your-choice>`

Answer (score 0):

There are now also VS Code extensions that allow viewing and editing the Zookeeper node hierarchy and data, like this one:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gaoliang.visual-zookeeper